# Python XML parser with a specific rule

Tags: python

I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--Generated by Screaming Frog SEO Spider 16.3-->
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://orinab.com/</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://orinab.com/cabinet/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%B4%D9%BE%D8%B2%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A8-%DA%86%D9%88%D8%A8%DB%8C</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://orinab.com/sales-associates</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://orinab.com/kitchen-cabinet/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%A8%DA%86%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AC</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  ...
```

and I want to append links with `kitchen-cabinet` rule to a list.
any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that good with xml, but one thing you can use is regex:

```py
import re
reg = re.compile(r'(https:.*kitchen-cabinet.*)(?=<)')
reg.findall(xml)

>> ['https://orinab.com/kitchen-cabinet/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%A8%DA%86%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AC']

# xml variable:
xml = '''
  <url>
    <loc>https://orinab.com/kitchen-cabinet/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%A8%DA%86%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AC</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://orinab.com/kitchen-cabinet/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%A8%DA%86%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AC</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://orinab.com/kitchen-cabinet/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%A8%DA%86%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AC</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
'''
reg.findall(xml)
>>> ['https://orinab.com/kitchen-cabinet/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%A8%DA%86%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AC',
 'https://orinab.com/kitchen-cabinet/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%A8%DA%86%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AC',
 'https://orinab.com/kitchen-cabinet/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%A8%DA%86%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AC']
```

Edit:

```
with open('file.xml', 'r') as f:
    trim = reg.findall(f.read())
    print(trim)
```

Comment: Thanks @3DspatialUser but I want the solution with the xml library

Comment: Which xml library do you want to use? There are multiple. Maybe you can close your XML file so it is a valid file and anyone can copy-paste your example.

Comment: doesn't matter which one until it comes to speed

Comment: Also I think your regex is not correct because it returns me an empty list

Comment: I do not understand why you want to use an external library if `re` ships with the default python installation. At my PCit does work, even if I repeat your xml snippet. It is expected that the variable `xml` is a string. I am not sure how you read your xml and why there is an error, but you do not provide much information to reproduce your error.

Comment: I have my xml file in a directory, it's not a variable

Answer (score 0):

The Python-docs have a [good introduction to using xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for parsing XML-files.

In general, you must use

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(<your_filename_here>)
root = tree.getroot()
```

to obtain a representation of your XML-file.

In your case, `root` will be the element `urlset`, and the next level of nesting are the `url`s. What complicates it a little bit is the fact that your XML introduces a namespace, but as per the instruction this is solved with defining a dictionary containing namespaces.

So if you do

```
ns = {'ns1': 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'}
kitchencabinets = []
for child in root:
    url = child.find('ns1:loc', ns).text
    if 'kitchen-kabinet' in url: kitchencabinets.append(url)
```

then `kitchencabinets` be a list the list you are after.